# Forming remainder modulo $n+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all positive integers $n$ for which a permutation  $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ of $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ can be found such that $0,  a_1 ,a_1+a_2 ,a_1+a_2+a_3 ,\ldots, a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n$ leave distinct remainder modulo $n+1$.

Comment: Any thoughts?  I think you can easily show that such an $n$ must be even...have you checked small $n$ for examples?

Comment: I have only found out a solution that is $n=3$.

Comment: In my first comment, I should have written "$n+1$ must be even" (or "$n$ must be odd").  Can you prove that $n=5$ or $n=7$ doesn't work?

Comment: For $n=5$ just take $\{5,2,3,4,1\}$.  What is the context for this problem? The first step is clearly to try lots of examples.  Try to find an odd counterexample.

Comment: @lulu if you take $(a_1,\dots, a_5)=(5,2,3,4,1)$ then $5+2+3\equiv 5\mod 6$, so that doesn't work.

Comment: @WillFisher Am I wrong?  $5+2+3=10\equiv 4 \pmod 6$.  No?

Comment: Sir 10 is congurant to 4 mod 6. @will fisher. Well I was trying to find a permutation for 7. I just found that the first number can not be 4 as the sum of all the numbers is 28 and that is 4 congurant to 8. May be trying to find the numbers backwards can lead a way.

Comment: @lulu Whoops completely just mistook $2+3$ for $6$, hah.

Comment: For $7$ I think just taking the numbers in order works.  I suggest searching odd numbers to see how often just the usual ordering works.

Comment: @WillFisher  Well, yesterday I based a calculation on the fact that $9^3$ was $81$.  Certainly made for interesting results!